# RPS code not runs but will not return any output

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I am trying to create a rock, paper, scissors game in PyCharm using Python 3.6.3 but it will not return any output upon execution and I have not received any code errors in my IDE.

```
import random

class RPS:
    rock = 1        
    paper = 2
    scissors = 3

    def __init__(self, choice):
        self.choice = choice

    def play(self):
        print("Enter: \n1 for Rock, \n2 for Paper, \nor 3 for Scissors")
        choice = int(input("Enter in a number between 1 and 3: "))
        while (choice != 1 or choice != 2 or choice != 3):
            print("You have selected an invalid choice!")
            print("Enter: \n1 for Rock, \n2 for Paper, \nor 3 for Scissors")
            choice = int(input("Enter in a number between 1 and 3: "))
            print("You have selected", choice)

        computer = random.randint(1, 3)

        if computer == 1:
            print("The computer chose rock")

        if computer == 2:
            print("The computer chose paper")

        if computer == 3:
            print("The computer chose scissors")

        if choice > computer:
            print("You win!")

        elif choice < computer:
            print("You lose!")

        elif choice == computer:
            print("It is a tie!")

        play_again = input('Do you want to play again[yes/no]? ')
        if play_again.lower() == 'yes':
            self.play()

        if play_again.lower() == 'no':
            print("Thanks for playing! \nBYE!")
```

Comment: This file imports a module and defines a class; at no point have you done anything to cause any code of yours to be executed.  You'd need to create an instance of your class, and invoke its `.play()` method.

Answer (score 0):

as jasonharper said, you aren't instancing the class and running it's play method.

to do that, add to the bottom of the file:

```
game = RPS()
game.play()
```

There are some other issues too, but I'll let you try to solve those yourself.